# Set method to change StartMode property using SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.Service

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I'm trying to change SQL server Configuration manager settings using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.Service`. Microsoft provided with a list of methods & properties here. I used the following code to change the Service account of a particular service:

```
$MyServerObject.SetServiceAccount($UName, $PWord)
```

because there exists a method called `SetServiceAccount`. But I do not understand/know how to set `StartMode` which a property. I know that currently my service says it is automatic,coz I can verify it using this line of code

```
$MyServerObject.StartMode
```

and the result is: `Auto`

Anybody knows how to set this property?

If someone wants to see what I'm talking about run these lines in PowerShell (Run as Administrator) on a computer where SQL Server is installed:

```
#Load assemblies
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlWmiManagement") | out-null

#Create Server Object
$SMOWmiserver = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer')

#Query Server object
$SMOWmiserver.Services | 
    select name, type, ServiceAccount, DisplayName, Properties, StartMode, StartupParameters | 
        Format-List

#Select a service
$MyServerObject=$SMOWmiserver.Services | where {$_.name -eq "MSSQLSERVER"}
$MyServerObject.StartMode
```

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully I can answer your question and explain how I did so.

To alter the service start mode using your code above you run

```
# Check Start Mode
$MyServerObject.StartMode
# Set Start Mode
$MyServerObject.StartMode ='Manual'
# Alter Start Mode
$MyServerObject.Alter()
# Check Start Mode again
$MyServerObject.StartMode
```

You can establish by using Get-Member as shown below

```
$MyServerObject|Get-Member
```

In the list of results you will see

StartMode                Property   Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ServiceStartMode StartMode {get;set;}

The {get;set;} shows that you can alter the property

You will also see

Alter                    Method     void Alter(), void IAlterable.Alter()

This is the method that you will use to apply the change to the object.

You can use the same principle throughout your PowerShell use.

It is also possible to do this remotely, if you have the correct privileges for your account, to do the following

```
# Get Service                                         
$Service = Get-WmiObject win32_service -ComputerName COMPUTERNAME -Filter "Name = 'MSSQLSERVER'"            
# Get Start Mode                         
$Service.StartMode     
# Change Start Mode                                                                                                                
$Service.ChangeStartMode('Manual') 
#Check Start Mode                                                                                                                    
$Service.StartMode
```

to achieve the same result